# How to update BIOS on HP desktop 290

Tags: hp, bios

HP Slim Desktop 290, running Xubuntu 22.04.    I've read thru all the threads on updating the bios without windows, but none of them seem to work for this computer.  Most are fairly old.   I don't have the option to update from a local file.  Some of the threads say to put the .bin file in /boot/efi/EFI/HP/BIOS, but in /boot/efi/EFI I don't have an HP directory.
Looking for suggestions.
Thx

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to Ubuntu, despite the cursory mention. For BIOS updates on HP PCs you should consult HP, or the support page of the specific model.

Comment: It's related to ubuntu because HP provides a windows based method, & they don't support anything else